# Joining three tables with OVER, for accumulative monthly figures

Tags: sql-server

I have made the amendments as per comments and entered here as not enough characters allowed in comments.  I think there may be a few issues on the OVER and with the JOIN.  Updated query:

```
SELECT RIGHT('0' + CAST(day(oh_datetime) AS VARCHAR (2)), 2),
SUM(SUM((CASE oh_sot_id WHEN 1 THEN 1 WHEN 4 THEN -1 END) * oht_net)) over (ORDER BY day(oh_datetime) ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS 'Orders In($)',
SUM((CASE oh_cd_id WHEN 11728 THEN 1 END) * oht_net) AS 'Target($)',
SUM(SUM((CASE ih_credit WHEN 'false' THEN 1 WHEN 'true' THEN -1 END) * ih_net)) over (ORDER BY day(ih_datetime) ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS 'Sales($)'
FROM order_header_total
JOIN order_header ON order_header_total.oht_oh_id = order_header.oh_id
JOIN invoice_header ON order_header.oh_id = invoice_header.ih_oh_id
WHERE oh_datetime >= DATEADD(day, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -1)) AND oh_datetime < DATEADD(day, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE()))
GROUP BY day(oh_datetime),  day(ih_datetime)
UNION SELECT 'YAxis','0','0','0'
```

Table should display:

| Date | Orders In | Target | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 6402.19 | 12321.57 | 128539.13 |
| 02 | 17795.94 | 24643.14 | 148258.63 |
| 03 | 50703.09 | 36964.71 | 171231.14 |
| 04 | 116034.29 | 49286.28 | 188157.69 |
| 28 | 353989.36 | 345004.00 | 446808.05 |

I have not done the full month for sake of space, but included the last day to show how it should accumulate.  Instead it looks like this:

| Date | Orders In | Target | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 5507.32 |  | 5507.32 |
| 01 | 5833.52 |  | 5833.52 |
| 01 | 6402.19 |  | 29377.18 |
| 02 | 10312.35 |  | 188157.69 |
| 02 | 16592.09 |  | 16023.42 |
| 02 | 17795.94 |  | 54950.68 |
| 03 | 30439.28 |  | 28666.76 |
| 03 | 30581.03 |  | 28808.51 |
| 04 | 36029.72 |  | 24700.77 |
| 04 | 37082.36 |  | 38767.55 |
| 23 | 144191.70 |  | 143992.45 |

Again a selection of data and then showing the last row for the sake of space.  The date is not grouping, 'Orders In' and 'Sales' are not accumulating, and there is no data displaying for 'Target'.

Comment: FYI, `WHERE` clauses like `YEAR(oh_datetime) = YEAR(GETDATE())` are *not* SARGable. I suggest using date boundaries for significantly better performance.

Comment: Also why the `FULL JOIN`s here? Your `WHERE` is going to filter out any row where `oh_datetime` doesn't meet the criteria (including where it has `NULL` when no row was found).

Comment: Thanks, I've had this suggestion on other queries, however if you set the date then it needs amending each month surely?  This query needs to be autonomous without date change inputs required.

Comment: Why would it need amending each month? It's using `GETDATE()`. What's wrong with, in pseudo sql `Oh_datetime >= {first day of this month based on GETDATE()} AND Oh_datetime < {first day of next month based on GETDATE()}`?

Comment: You can do `oh.Oh_datetime >= DATEADD(day, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -1)) AND oh.oh_datetime < DATEADD(day, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE())`. Also why use `UNION` rather than `UNION ALL`

Comment: Anyway to answer your question, it's probably because you are missing `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` in the `OVER`. Without actual sample data and expected results can't say for sure